# Solid state relays with 555 timer for spark plug circuit

Tags: relay, plug, spark

So here is the circuit that I have tried to make it work with an ignition coil to make sparks. What I want to achieve is a single spark from the input. This circuit does work but the IC 555 timer burned after a few sparks. Also I am having quite a but of back emf from the coil since the coil ratio is 1:100. I was thinking of using solid state relays along with the protection circuit around the Mofset to control it but I am not sure how to achieve my goal of getting a single spark with this timer. [image]

Comment: You need a diode across the terminals of the ignition coil to pass the back-EMF when it turns off.

Comment: @vir Why, as there already is the RCD snubber for back-EMF?

Comment: Maybe I'm reading the schematic wrong but I am not familiar with that snubber placement.  I can see how it should work in theory but the 555 is still getting burnt.

Comment: Ok so when I tried it, I didnt use a protection across the Mofset i.e. the diode array with the snubber so maybe that's why the 555 timer got burnt. I can fix that problem by putting the protection circuit for the mofset but how do I get a single spark with a solid state relay in this? Also is there another way to control the back emf since there's quite of it

Comment: @vir can you please indicate where exactly the diode should go and how it should be connected?

Comment: I don't think a solid state relay would give you much benefit here.  Try a Schottky diode rated at least for the same current as your coil directly across the terminals of the ignition coil, cathode towards +12V, anode towards the MOSFET.

Comment: @vir can you please tell me why you think the solid state relay won't work to generate a single spark?

Comment: That 100k resistor in the RCD snubber lets the back emf rise to a voltage of Icoil * 100k. Advantage of this arrangement is a fairly fast coil current switch off time. It's possible that the large back emf could be being capacitively coupled from the drain back to the gate and blowing the 555. Use a schottky diode across the coil (already suggested) which will limit the back emf to about 0.4V and schottkys are fairly quick. What's that diode & resistor doing in the ground line - never seen that arrangement before! Consider configuring the 555 as a monostable to get a single pulse out of it.